# How to use web3.js@1.0.0-beta34 with TypeScript?

Tags: web3js, typescript

Here is a minimal code for testing:

```
import * as Web3 from "web3"

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"))

const main = async () => {
  const blockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
  console.log({ blockNumber })
}

main().catch(err => console.error(err))
```

The module typings are wrong. If I try to compile it, there are some errors:

```
maxblock@mbp t10-web3-typescript *$ npm run build

> t10-web3-typescript@1.0.0 build /Users/maxblock/projects/test/t10-web3-typescript
> rimraf dist && tsc

../../../node_modules/web3/types.d.ts(1,27): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'bn.js'. '/Users/maxblock/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/bn.js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bn.js';`
../../../node_modules/web3/types.d.ts(2,21): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'underscore'. '/Users/maxblock/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/underscore` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'underscore';`
src/index.ts(3,14): error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
src/index.ts(3,32): error TS2339: Property 'providers' does not exist on type 'typeof "/Users/maxblock/node_modules/web3/index"'.
```

OK. Next, I tried to override typings with my own. For this reason, I've created a file typings.d.ts with simple stub: `declare module "web3"`.

There are fewer errors with my own typings, but anyway I can't compile it:

```
maxblock@mbp t10-web3-typescript *$ npm run build

> t10-web3-typescript@1.0.0 build /Users/maxblock/projects/test/t10-web3-typescript
> rimraf dist && rimraf node_modules/web3/index.d.ts && rimraf node_modules/web3/types.d.ts && tsc

../../../node_modules/web3/types.d.ts(1,27): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'bn.js'. '/Users/maxblock/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/bn.js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bn.js';`
../../../node_modules/web3/types.d.ts(2,21): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'underscore'. '/Users/maxblock/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/underscore` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'underscore';`
```

I've even tried deleting node_modules/web3/index.d.ts and node_modules/web3/types.d.ts files, but without success.

How do you work with web3.js + TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

Under your project root folder where `package.json` is located, run these commands:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/underscore
npm install bignumber.js
```

or

```
yarn add @types/underscore --dev
yarn add bignumber.js
```

edit first line of `<rootDir>/node_moduoles/web3/types.d.ts` as below:

```
-- import { BigNumber } from 'bn.js'
++ import { BigNumber } from 'bignumber.js'
```

your code should compile

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

1. Install `node` types.

   ```
   npm install @types/node --save
   ```
2. Specify `node` types in `tsconfig.json`:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       // rest ommitted,
       "types": ["node"]
     },
     "typeRoots": [
       "./node_modules/@types"
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Use `require` syntax instead of `import * as Web3 from 'web3';`:

   ```
   const Web3 = require('web3');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide types for the two mentioned libraries, `underscore` and `bn.js`. The first one is easy, simply run `npm install --save-dev @types/underscore` as it suggested. Unfortunately, the latter has no `@types/bn.js` package available. But you can find type definitions for it around, here's one you can copy into your project: https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/MyCrypto/blob/develop/common/typescript/bn.d.ts

You should not edit files inside of `node_modules` to get things working, as those changes won't carry over for anyone else or you when you re-download or update the module in your project.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use Inject.

install using **npm install web3@latest**

and

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

export const WEB3 = new InjectionToken<Web3>('web3',{
    providedIn : 'root',
    factory: () => {
        try {
            const provider = ('ethereum' in window) ? window['ethereum'] : Web3.givenProvider;
            return new Web3(provider);
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('No Ethereum provider');
        }
    }
});
```

and use this in any other class.

```
constructor(@Inject(WEB3) private web3: Web3){

    this.web3 = new Web3(this.provider);
    this.contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(this.contractABI, this.contractAddress);

}
```